# Running OpenRDF Sesame through proxied apache

Tags: apache, tomcat, rdf, sesame, proxypass

My Tomcat ist proxied through Apache as follows:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /tomcat/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/
ProxyPassReverse /tomcat/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

Calling `http://example.com/tomcat` loads my Tomcat server (as expected).

Now I putted the `openrdf-sesame.war` and `openrdf-workbench.war` into my webapps folder. If I open

- http://example.com/tomcat/openrdf-workbench it fowards to http://example.com/openrdf-workbench
- http://example.com/tomcat/openrdf-sesame/ it forwards to https://example.com/openrdf-sesame/overview.view

During the forwarding, the path-part `/tomcat` is lost.

How can I configure a base-path (e.g. `/tomcat`) in OpenRDF Sesame, so the forwardning does not fail?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to fix this is just to include a Sesame-specific reverse proxy to your Apache config (incidentally I'd use ajp proxying instead of http, if you can - it's more efficient):

```
    ProxyPass /openrdf-sesame ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/openrdf-sesame
    ProxyPassReverse /openrdf-sesame ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/openrdf-sesame
```

And for the Workbench:

```
    ProxyPass /openrdf-workbench ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/openrdf-workbench
    ProxyPassReverse /openrdf-workbench ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/openrdf-workbench
```